# Global callback for Ajax calls in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

Is it possible to create and attach a callback which would get called whenever an ajax request completes regardless of whether the call was made using `$.ajax`, `$.post`, `load` or any other function?

**EDIT:**

The solution given by Nakul (using ajaxSuccess global event) is almost perfect. However I have a problem when using this with the `load` function. The ajaxSuccess event is raised after the request has completed but before any DOM manipulation. I would like to execute some code after the DOM has been modified. My temporary solution is to use `setTimeout` and wait for a couple of milliseconds but I don't think it'd be reliable enough for me.

So another question is: how can you execute code after the DOM has been manipulated by the `load` function?

**EDIT 2:**

I've managed to solve the second issue by using ajaxComplete event instead of ajaxSuccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ajaxSuccess](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxSuccess)
More here: http://www.slideshare.net/wildan.m/jquery-talk-to-server-with-ajax (after slide 47)

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for, but I have another problem; I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ajaxSuccess` and maybe you want to run the code when you click a link?

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="runCode">Run code</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() { // same as dom loaded
    $('a.runCode').click(function() {
        alert('whatever you want to do here');
    });
});
```